# Getting unique hardware ID changes everytime C#

Tags: c#, .net, uuid

I want to make a program and sell it, so I was thinking to make some kind of licensing system. What I've found on google is this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28678/Generating-Unique-Key-Finger-Print-for-a-Computer

I am running Windows 7 (32 bit) in VirtualBox from Ubuntu. I get the same UID, but when I restart my Windows, I get a new UID. I am just thinking that some people will buy my program and they may run it from VirtualBox, so it would be a problem.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Even if it's an easier way, but something that won't change even if I restart my VBox.

Comment: Even if id would be the same every time, they just could clone the VM and use your program in thousand places anyway.

Comment: First rule: don't reinvent the wheel. Someone else already did it, probably better :)

Comment: don't understand, why did I got -3 ?

Comment: You probably got downvoted because this isn't a specific coding question.  [This is what's on topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to not get so bogged down in the whole DRM process, there are always smarter people out there and someone will work out how to circumvent it.

If you're really concerned:

1. Set up an online license server to hold your users licenses
2. Prevent the application from doing anything until the user enters a valid license

   - This licence would be validated over the internet by your service
   - You could restrict the number of "active" applications using your service that way

Think along the lines of how iTunes allows you to authorise up to 5 computers to access your media library.

Comment: Well, actually. I will have a database on a server. With email,password,uid. Once they buy the program (with paypal) I will enter that email into my DB, with some random password. When they open the program for the first time, the program should get the UID, and put it in the uid column of my database. When they will run it again, it will just check if it's the same.

Comment: @user2051154 then go this route, creating hardware ID's is a no-no, what if they change a piece of their hardware like the processor or graphics card? You risk your software locking them out.

Comment: you're right ... but how should I generate that UID then ? The program is not something BIG, it's actually my first one (for "bulk" selling). Do you think it would be ok if I just user the computer's name ? I know ... it damn easy to break. But I hope to keep the product out of leaking for a while ...

Comment: @user2051154 I wouldn't recommend creating any ID for each machine, if you choose a number of machines the user can install simultaneously on and have it so your software can be "activated" and "deactivated" on these machines and just increment or decrement the number of used machines in your database, that way you can still control how many machines they install on, without any complicated bypassable logic.

Comment: Well, it's just a simple software tbh. It's actually an interactive trainer, for a BIG software. Do you think it would be a wise decision when the user logs in (via the program), to have actually not uid column, but active column in my db. When the user is authorized, it will put 1 in the active column. When it closes the program entirely, it will put 0. So it will run only one computer at a time (let's say ... this to be the licensing system)

Comment: @user2051154 that would be a wise decision to make it simpler to manage, but I warn against restricting it to a single machine, some users may not enjoy that limitation. If your app is simple enough, might I suggest targeting the Windows 8 store and sell it that way? You get the knowledge it's only running on machines that belong to the user who bought the app and you get to jump on the latest bandwagon plus exposure.

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy :) I will write this informations in the description, before selling the program, so that people will know it will run only on one computer at a time. THanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Even if a lot of time has passed, I want to add a possible solution to this question, pointing out something that happened to me trying to generate a fingerprint with exactly that code and facing the same problem.

The `identifier` function retrieves **only the first not-empty value** of `wmiProperty` for each `wmiClass`. The first important thing you should be aware of is this: what is returned for every `wmiClass` *might not* belong to the same ManagementObject. Hence, if something changes to "not the first object", this might affect also your fingerprint.

Be advised that using `Win32_DiskDrive` as `wmiClass` is dangerous since plugging in a USB device often results in this device being recognized as the first one (instead of your hard drive), changing the fingerprint as you plug-in or out your device. Even if this doesn't happen, still one of the `wmiProperty` could be taken from your USB device if your main drive has it empty (*e.g.* the disk signature, which happened to me).

A possible solution to that would be excluding all USB devices by checking `InterfaceType` and excluding all those who match "USB", or at least that's what I did.